# The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My stored procedure is trying to write a record in to a database on another Server. The statement is here:

```
IF @Builds > 0
   BEGIN
        SET @DPU = @Failures / @Builds
        INSERT INTO SQL05.ManufacturingPortal.dbo.OPC.WriteRequests (ID, RegisterID, Value, RequestedDate, IsCompleted)
        VALUES(@PLCID, 'F8:10' , CAST(@DPU AS NUMERIC(10,2)), GETDATE(), 0)    
    END
```

However when I try to create the stored procedure - I get the following error:

> The object name 'SQL05.ManufacturingPortal.dbo.OPC.WriteRequests' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.

I have tried creating an alias of Server.DB.DBO to shorten the number of prefixes however seem to be implementing this wrong.

I cannot change my database schema on the target database. Any suggestions on how I can get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Correct four-part table name is server.database.schema.tablename - you have some excess parts there.

Looks like table name is OPC.WriteRequests? If yes, then you have to use brackets: `SQL05.ManufacturingPortal.dbo.[OPC.WriteRequests]`

But maybe you just have some part of name incorrect?

Comment: +1 Good guess. I would refrain from such table names. They add more to the confusion than doing any good. If at all a two word table name is needed, either use Pascal Casing or use _ to join the words.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is correct, in that the example given literally has too many prefixes.  In the example, one prefix had a dot in its name, and needs to be set off by square brackets (or better yet, have a name that conforms to convention).

In my case, it actually wanted to be run on the server where the INTO table would live:

```
SELECT * 
INTO [database].[schema].[table] 
FROM [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```

Comment: Having the source as linked server, instead of vice versa, worked for me as well. SELECT INTO where the destination is a linked server seems not to be a workable option.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are receiving the error is because you are not using a valid name. You appear to be referencing two schemata, `dbo` and `OPC`.

The valid syntax is `server_name.database_name.schema_name.object_name` as referenced on the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for `INSERT`.

Remove the incorrect schema and try again.

Comment: Hi, The table name is "OPC.WriteRequests"... I know - I didn't write it :-( !

Comment: In that case, you just need to qualify the table name with square brackets like this `[OPC.WriteRequests]`.

Answer (score 6):

I was using everything correct still the issue persisted. My command was like below

```
select * into server.database.schema.table from table2
```

I resolved it by creating the table in the server first and then used the insert into statement which executed without issues

```
Create Table...........
Insert into server.database.schema.table  select * from table2
```

Thanks,
Sree

Comment: That's also what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

use with braket "[]" for name and remote database server like this.
[87.247.678.80,1666].[danesfe].[admin1].[homefarsi]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues where I was getting the message when I was trying to execute the following code(make table)

`"into SalesCube_temp.SalesCube_temp.dbo.ALL_SUPPLIER_SALES_METRICS_I"`

I then Realized that I was using the incorrect Syntax and then rectified as

`"into SalesCube_temp.dbo.ALL_SUPPLIER_SALES_METRICS_I"`

IT WORKED, END OF MY STORY. But I spent nearly 10 to 15 minutes tr

Hope it will help somebody.

Comment: in your example there is no linked server isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

My (inherited) code was using string.Format and passing the server name, eg

```
string.Format("Select * from {0}.AwesomeDB.dbo.EpicTable", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MuhServerName"]);
```

but in the config, "MuhServerName" was "MyServer.MyDomain.com/MyInstance", so it was loaded as

```
Select * from MyServer.MyDomain.com/MyInstance.AwesomeDB.dbo.EpicTable
```

instead of

```
Select * from [MyServer.MyDomain.com/MyInstance].AwesomeDB.dbo.EpicTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved basicly.

```
CREATE VIEW view_LINKSERVERTABLE AS   
SELECT * FROM LINKSERVERNAME.DBNAME.DBO.TABLENAME
```

and then

```
  INSERT INTO view_LINKSERVERTABLE SELECT * FROM database
```

Answer (score -1):

Please change the tables from the start and try to insert with the normal way

```
Use ManufacturingPortal 

IF @Builds > 0

   BEGIN

       SET @DPU = @Failures / @Builds

       INSERT INTO OPC.WriteRequests (ID, RegisterID, Value, RequestedDate, IsCompleted)
       VALUES(@PLCID, 'F8:10' , CAST(@DPU AS NUMERIC(10,2)), GETDATE(), 0)    

   END
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.
The problem was due to the following mistake: instead of passing `textbox1.text` as argument to the query being called from code-behind i passed `textbox1`.

Hope it helps