# How to Format the following Server Name to Call Tables from another Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to call tables from a different server. However, there is a problem since the server name appears in the following format:

```
10.52.49.22/Name
```

Now if I do something like this, I get the error, "

> The object name contains more than the maximum number of prefixes

```
SELECT t1.[UserId]
FROM [10.52.49.22].Name.[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableOne] t1
JOIN [10.52.49.22].Name.[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableTwo] t2
on t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

How to use this server name correctly against the syntax specified in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26119669/2093880)?

Comment: Can you try something like [10.52.49.22\Name].[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableOne]? You can also create [Synonyms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx) to wrap details.

Comment: @Shishir, I tried but I get the following error, "Could not find server '10.52.49.22/Name' in sys.servers."

Comment: Please create [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) then execute query for remote server. Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just toss the name of another server in the middle of a query like that. To reference an external server you need to use a link server. And the syntax you have there is not ever going to work. The longest you can have is 4 part naming. You have 5....not sure what Name is there.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Your query would be something like this.

```
SELECT t1.[UserId]
FROM [YourLinkServerName].[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableOne] t1
JOIN [YourLinkServerName].[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableTwo] t2
on t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

Comment: In a connection string, Name would look like this while 53909 is a port number: Data Source=10.52.49.22,53909\Name;

Comment: Not sure what your connection string has to do with this. If you are already connecting to that server you don't need to specify the server again.

Comment: I know this is strange. But any way, I found that a linked server is already created on the server I am trying to call from, and the LinkServerName is like this: Name\Name. So I just added it as it is and it worked: FROM [Name\Name].[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableOne] t1

Answer (score 0):

Name.[TargetDatabase] should be one.

```
[10.52.49.22].[TargetDatabase].[dbo].[TableOne]
```

Comment: This returns an error, "Could not find server '10.52.49.22' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers."

Comment: You need to use the name as it appears in the linked servers list.  From the other posts, it seems you know that now.  Cheers