# How I can copy a table in an other server with SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 
    *
into
    [Server1].[MyDB].[dbo].[_ListClientBEBRUT]
from
    [Server2].[MyDB].[dbo].[_ListClientBEBRUT]
```

But it returns me an error :

```
Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
The object name 'Server1.MyDB.dbo._ListClientBEBRUT' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.
```

Could you please tell me how i can fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119343/the-object-name-contains-more-than-the-maximum-number-of-prefixes-the-maximum-i

Comment: 4-part naming is `server.database.schema.object` - are you trying to copy your table into another schema, another database, or another server?

Comment: An other server year you're right

Comment: `dbo` is your schema here, *not* your linked servers that are oddly called `Schema1` and `Schema2`.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - "You cannot create new_table on a remote server;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Server1.MyDb.dbo._ListClientBEBRUT is the server.db.schema.table where I want to copy my data from Server2.MyDb.dbo._ListClientBEBRUT

1. Connect on the destination server in the correct data base (in my ex : Server1.MyDb)
2. Run this query

---

```
select 
    *
into
    _ListClientBEBRUT
from
    [Server2].[MyDB].[dbo].[_ListClientBEBRUT]
```

Some usefull links :

[Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44047997/11203927)

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)